# Exception using Play framework JPA updating unique constraint field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

After deleting 1 value from a unique field (Mysql) i need to rename 
the remaining values again in one  transaction :
the code:

```
JPA.withTransaction(new Callback0() {
            @Override
            public void invoke() throws Throwable {
                obj.removeDevice(deviceID);
            // if I put removeDevice in different transaction it works !
            // but can cause integrity problem i case of failure    
                obj.changeTemporalDevices(...); 
                obj.reCalcDevicesNames(...);

               obj.saveDevices(....);

            }
        });
```

It's seems that JPA does not "see" that  a value has been deleted in one transaction and i got the  exception below:

```
[ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'aaa2r28c011' for key 'name_device_UNIQUE'
[ERROR] application - javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:111) ~[play-java-jpa_2.10-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should flush your session right after the deletion in order to not let hibernate chooses the SQL statement execution order.

Comment: You could mark the response as the correct one then. Thank you.